# tikzexternalize: Contour filled plot is plotted in external file but not main file

Tags: tikz-pgf, miktex, tikz-external

I updated my Miktex distribution today and some things refuse to work now.

For example `contour filled` plots, when they are externalized: they just show an empty axis. It is weird though, that the actual external file is correct!

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer,patchplots}

\usetikzlibrary{external}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix={}]

\begin{document}

\tikzexternalenable
\tikzsetnextfilename{testplot}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{axis}[
    width=0.8\linewidth,
    height=0.4\textwidth,
    domain=3:15,
    domain y=0:20,
    view={0}{90},
    grid=none,
    colorbar,
    point meta min = 0,
    point meta max = 60,
    colorbar style={
        samples=11,
        ytick={0,10,...,60},
    },
    ]

    \addplot3[contour filled={number=12}]  
        {x*y*(2*3.14*30)/1000};

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### main output pdf file

[image]

### external output pdf file

[image]

Do you have an explanation and any idea hot to fix this?

Thank you!

### the log files

[testplot.log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ak14fj7kxv4a8ny/testplot.log?dl=0)
[testdocument.log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/enz0e4ka10r3toz/testdocument.log?dl=0)

Comment: Your plot doesn't give the picture you are showing.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer what do you mean, it doesn't give the picture? I compiled it another time on another computer, it returns exactly that. (There was one line which could have thrown an error, I removed it.)

Comment: Well giving an error would surely count as not producing the output shown, so surely there is a ready explanation for what @UlrikeFischer meant? What does the log say? For the plot and/or the main document? It works OK for me on TeX Live.

Comment: @cfr when I viewed the plot in sumatra  and it looked completly different as with the adobe viewer.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It looks as shown in Okular with the current edited version of the code. I can't really test the others. (I could try to test acroread, but probably not successfully.)

Comment: @cfr - weirdly enough, because that line didn't threw an error on my pc (thats why I didn't notice), even though the used tikzstyle was not loaded.

Comment: @cfr logfiles are attached now.

Comment: You're using LuaTeX. However, it works for me with that, too. Can you add `\listfiles` to the MWE and recompile? Then post the list of files and versions you get so we can compare. It would be good if a MikTeX user could test this, though.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer can confirm the problem, so it looks as if this is going to be reproduceable only on MikTeX. David reports it works fine, but that's with TL2016, which is also what I'm using. I've added a couple of tags reflecting all this. Can you reproduce with other engines or is it LuaTeX specific? If it is LuaTeX specific, we should add that tag, too, maybe.

Comment: I will look at it in a few hours.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem but have no idea what happens. I made a bug report: https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2593/

Comment: @UlrikeFIscher thanks a lot for all your effort! I'm actually installing texlive right now, to do some version comparisons, but you were faster. I tried various plot types and `contour filled` seems to be the only affected. Interesting is also, that in my case also the colorbar is affected, but colorbars in general work without problems.

Comment: Christian thinks that he can fix it. See https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2593/